# Selecting from a nested array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have the following array

```
const accounts =[{'accounts':{id:1,name: 'Jill','occupation': 'Welder'}, {id:2,name: 'John','occupation': 'Driver'}, {id:3,name: 'Steve','occupation': 'Accountants'}}, 
{'accounts':{id:1,name: 'James','occupation': 'Welder'},{id:1,name: 'Steve','occupation': 'Security'},{id:1,name: 'Sarah','occupation': 'Waiter'}}, 
{'accounts':{id:1,name: 'George','occupation': 'Developer'},{id:1,name: 'Andrew','occupation': 'Security'},{id:1,name: 'Frank','occupation': 'Welder'}}];
```

and I would like to be able to make a selection of like Welder or driver etc...

I have tried using this

```
const welders= accounts.filter(x => x.accounts.every(ls1=> ls1.occupation ==='Welder'));
```

but it returns an empty array.

Can someone suggest the best way to achieve it

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: try in chrome, no error just an empty array but I got an answer from @iamentafaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const welders= accounts.map(x => x.accounts.filter(ls1=> ls1.occupation ==='Welder' || ls1.occupation ==='Driver'));
```

Comment: cheers thanks that did it. Thanks a bunch. Will accept in 5

Comment: Could you please accept the answer @JackM?